# Path Problem with Custom Prestashop module

Tags: prestashop

Can someone help me with a file path problem I am experiencing with a custom Prestashop module 1.6 version?

The following works perfectly in a localhost environment:

```
return $this->display(__FILE__, '../../product-list.tpl');
```

however does not work on a live server. The following does work:

```
return $this->display(__FILE__, '../../themes/default-bootstrap/product-list.tpl');
```

which is not acceptable as some customers will not be using the default-bootstrap theme.

Any assistance with this problem will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

"$this->display" command has many dependencies on ModuleCore **SO** it's better to use include on custom tpl file:

```
return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/custom.tpl');
```

then on your custom.tpl  :

```
{include file="$tpl_dir./product-list.tpl" products=$products}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, but the link is from the custom module's php to display the product-list.tpl which is in the themes/default-bootstrap folder.

Comment: I've used this way many times for the same job. $tpl_dir is the predefined smarty variable on prestashop equals your theme directory address

Comment: Thanks again for your help, but the $tpl_dir does not help my problem.