# How to display theme's .tpl in module (in hook)?

Tags: module, smarty, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I am making a module, that suposed to use templates from my custom theme.

The problem is that I don't understand the function Module::display(), it gets two arguments "file" and "template", what is the file? What is it for? 
If I do this:

```
public function hookDisplayHome{
        return $this->display(__FILE__, '../../templates/my_custom_theme/mb_templates/aboutus.tpl');
    }
```

It displays error "Not found template file" in module "my_module". Of course if I change the template path to one of the templates of my module, then it works. But I need to access theme's template, not my module's.

With this I have also another additional question. Is there any documentation on Prestashop's functions? I really tried to analyse the function $this -> display() but couldn't find any place where is described what are the arguments of this function etc. There is Prestashop documentation https://devdocs.prestashop.com but it is very general, and has no description of the functions. 
I've checked the class Module.php, the function has no comments :(
What is the official way when you want to check what the function does, returns, and what parameters accepts? It has to be somewhere, right?

Answer (score 1):

So for those who also struggle with this problem, based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53576139/2796533

The easiest solution seems to be using module's template in $this -> display() and then in that template include the theme's template:

```
{include file='../../../themes/my_custom_theme/mb_templates/aboutus.tpl'}
```